# Find and Print high number array method Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, numbers, find

What I’m attempting to do is search “gradePsd” array find the highest grade and if there are two grades that are the same value print the name (s) of the students to console.

The problem I’m having is that this method is taking the first index value of the array and printing it because it IS the high value at the first pass and if the second value is larger than the first then it will also print and so on.

So my question is how can I get it to just print the student (s) with the high grade.

```
public static void hiMarkMethod(String[] NamePsd, int[] gradePsd)
{
    String nameRtn = "";
    int num = gradePsd[0];

    System.out.println ("\n\nThe Student(s) with Hightest Mark(s) are:");

    for (int  i = 0; i < gradePsd.length;  i++)
    {
        if (gradePsd[i] >= num)
        {
            num = gradePsd[i];
            nameRtn = NamePsd[i]; 
        }

        System.out.print(nameRtn + ", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first find the highest number
then print the students with that number

```
public static void hiMarkMethod(String[] NamePsd, int[] gradePsd)
    {

    String nameRtn = "";
    int num = gradePsd[0];

     System.out.println ("\n\nThe Student(s) with Hightest Mark(s) are:");
    //find the highest number
    for (int  i = 0; i < gradePsd.length;  i++){
    if (gradePsd[i] >= num){
        num = gradePsd[i];
    }
    //print students with that number
    for (int  j = 0; j < NamePsd.length;  j++){
        if (gradePsd[j] == num)
        {
            nameRtn = NamePsd[j]; 
            System.out.print(nameRtn + ", "); 
        }
    }
```

one of possible 1000 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `num` with -1 and take the `System.out` out of the for loop. But you can only determine one student with your code. You need `nameRtn` to be a `Collection` if you want to store more than one name.

Something like this:

```
public static void hiMarkMethod(String[] NamePsd, int[] gradePsd) {
    Collection<String> namesRtn = new ArrayList<String>();
    int num = -1;

    for (int  i = 0; i < gradePsd.length;  i++) {
        if (gradePsd[i] > num) {
            num = gradePsd[i];
            namesRtn.clear();  // clear name list as we have a new highest grade
            namesRtn.add(NamePsd[i]);  // store name in list
        } else if (gradePsd[i] == num) {
            namesRtn.add(NamePsd[i]);  // if a second student has the same grade store it to the list
        }

    }
    System.out.println ("\n\nThe Student(s) with Hightest Mark(s) are: " + namesRtn);
}
```